# Правда ли, что слово "истина" ни с чем не рифмуется?

Tags: стихи

Прочитала где-то, что слово "истина" ни с чем не рифмуется. Сама придумать рифму не смогла. Может, кто-то сможет опровергнуть это утверждение?))

Comment: Время идет, вот и учебники новые,  
В них прописана ***"свежая истина"***...  
"Мы, нацисты, были ребята клевые!" -
Улыбается старый ***фашистина***.

Comment: Это утверждение В.Набокова в его лекциях, он прав,до сих пор никто точной рифмы не нашёл, он говорил именно про точную и из одного слова, не составную, неточных и составных можно найти много, например, истина - и стена ...

Comment: Не проблема:
ИСТИНА - ЗАЛЫСИНА.
Я всегда употребляю эту рифму.

Иногда беру:
ИСТИНА - ЧИСТИМА.

Comment: >Не проблема: ИСТИНА - ЗАЛЫСИНА. Я всегда употребляю эту рифму.  
  
Можно поинтересоваться, Вы много стихов написали?
Незнайка рифмовал, кажется, "палка" и "зеленка".

Comment: ИСТИНА - Хуистина

Comment: @Vadizar пожалуйста, используйте для ответа ответ, а не комментарий.

Comment: https://rifme.net/r/%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/2. Например, смолистая

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Есть ли рифма к слову *Истина*" - 
Я спросил у Охлобыстина. 
Кто напишет продолжение,   
Тот заслужит уважение.

(+) 
-"Я всегда держал Набокова 
За мыслителя глубокого.
Только рифма к слову Истина -
аналойно-эвхаристинна!"

Answer (score 23):

Вопрос, конечно, жизненный

Про рифму к слову истина,

Где тот поэт единственный?

Велик он будет – истинно.

Восславим мы прижизненно:

Он Гений, бог стиха  воистину!

Но где же рифма к истине?-

История таинственна!

Answer (score 11):

Точной рифмы одним словом скорей всего действительно нет. Неточную рифму в косвенных падежах.

> А вам известна истина,
> Что осень сыплет листьями?

Или

> А вам известна истина,
> Что сок не гасят известью?
>
> А вам известна истина,
> Что миссис тянет к мистерам?

Почти наверняка можно придумать составную, что-то вроде **истина - лист и на**, сударением на первом слове.

Answer (score 9):

```
                             Б А Л Л А Д А  О Б  И С Т И Н Е

                        Если рифму хочешь найти к слову «истина»,
                        Ты Ивана спроси Охлобыстина.
                        Хоть позиция у него и воинственна,
                        Да и тема довольно таинственна,
                        Он тебе объяснит, даже письменно,
                        Что искомая рифма немыслима,
                        А попытка её отыскать -  бессмысленна.
                        Она сразу же будет освистана,
                        Ведь слепая толпа неистова.
                        Всем известно об этом издавна,
                        А трудов по затронутой теме куча издана.
                        Пусть походка у Ваньки  расхристана,
                        И на лбу есть большая залысина,
                        Не одна им хорошая книга написана,
                        Да и чужих не одна пролистана.
                        Ну, а значит, его резолюция истинна,
                        Как то, что осень салютует листьями нам,
                        И то, что страсть к рифмованию жизненна,
                        Хотя страсть, сама по себе, и низменна.
                        Очень хитрая наука - лингвистика,
                        Её логика прямо убийственна,
                        Рифма к истине – это мистика,
                        А где мистике место, там отсутствует истина.
                        Не дай Бог, рифма будет отыскана,
                        Ведь исчезнет тогда абсолютная истина,
                        К заурядным словам она будет причислена,
                        И от рифмы своей станет зависима.
                        Та ко лжи повернёт, а хвостом за ней истина,
                        И случится, что истина станет неистинна.
                        Не спасёт мир тогда евхаристия,
                        И не будет пути, чтобы дальше брести нам.
                        Но судьба её, к счастью, давно предвосхи́щена,
                        Ещё Набоковым стезя ей от рифм расчищена,
                        Как Божья Троица в веках пусть будет Истина
                        Абсолютна, непогрешима, и единственна!!!
                        С благословления иерея Ивана Охлобыстина.
```

Answer (score 5):

Моя [любимая программка](http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe) знает 16 вариантов точных рифм на слово "и́стина": [по-,про-,пере-]ли́стана, [о-,об-,на-,от-,по-,про-,пере-]сви́стана, расхри́стана, [не-]и́стинна, при́станна.

Под точной рифмой (добавлю - в данном случае) понимается полное совпадение (с учетом редукции гласных) орфоэпического вида послеударной части слов.

Comment: Вы, кроме *истина-неистинна*, не привели ни одного примера точной рифмы. Хотя и эти слова не уверен, что можно назвать рифмой, корень-то один и тот же. В остальных случаях третий и четвёртый звук с конца слова не совпадают - [Ис**т'ь**нъ] - перел[Ис**тъ**нъ]

Comment: Дело даже не в корне. Однокоренная рифма - тоже рифма, только "непоэтическая". Но, если подходить строго, в данном случае она еще и неточная. В этой позиции двойное НН не редуцируется до одинарного.  
Редуцированные А и Е в первом заударном слоге тоже, кстати, заметно разнятся. Это помимо смягчения предыдущего согласного.

Comment: Да, строго говоря, это так.  

Но редуцированные гласные произносятся так нечётко, что такая рифма, не будучи "точной" в формальном смысле, всё-таки лучше других созвучий.   

А смягчения и удваивания согласных ещё менее существенны.

А рифма "истина/истинна", конечно, не "ботинок/полуботинок" (всё-таки разные части речи), но и не сахар - омонимичной её вряд ли можно счесть, слишком близок смысл.

Answer (score 3):

Говорят, что истине
Альтернативы нет!
В чём состоит тогда
Её неведомый секрет?
Нет пары ей
Ни в жизни,
Ни в уме!?
Так где ж её искать? 
В какой такой стране?
Мистическое слово?!
- Не может быть такого!
Я атеист, 
Но верю в чудеса!
Истина не милостыня! 
Истина - единственна!
Истина - таинственна!
Истина - божественна!
Истина - краса!

Comment: В поисках истины
Точной рифмы на "истина"
На память пришла 
"орфоэп-истина."
Понятие - новое!
Пусть бестолковое!
 Но звучание его
 - далеко не хреновое!
Есть у меня подруга,
Кр-истина, 
Может, она мне подскажет наивно,
Будет каким искомое слово. 
Блондинка, правда, она. 
Но к  кому обратиться ещё,
Если нет "варианта иного?! "

Answer (score 3):

(Екатерине Каштановой - за идею)

*Пьется горькая истина -

Под гармонь и до дна.

А жена гармонистина

Все гуляет одна.*
(Продолжение следует)))).

А вообще Набоков не прав.

Русский человек даже к "Эйяфьятлайокудль" рифму подберет.

Я не шучу.

*Мы сидели с тобой у окна,

Поедая твой яблочный штрудель.

Нам обоим уже не до сна,

Потому что Эйяфьятлайокудль*
(С)Не я

(автора не знаю, но это - пять с плюсом).

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос! А ответы ещё интереснее. Предложу свою рифму без всякой надежды на её приятие:

*Вот вам истина:
шапка - Митина!*

Comment: Это рифмоид. Набоков такое не принял бы. Вот если бы шапка было Мистина...Но  краду у вас идею.

Comment: Интересно... Ударение совпадает, два заударных слога совпадают. Рифма довольно точная. Вы уверены, что это рифмоид? Только потому, что нет [с'] в ударном слоге? Впрочем, я и сама чувствую, что ЭТО не совсем ТО!

Comment: Уверен. "Довольно точная" не принимается. Она должна быть стопроцентно точная, фонетическая (неразличимо или почти неразличимо на слух). Единственное послабление (необщепринятое) - дифтонги переднего ряда на -Й. Так, ИЙ рифмуется с простым И - и т. п. А у вас "С" вполне себе произносится.

Answer (score 1):

А есть ли рифма к слову «истина»?
Спросили мы у Охлобыстина.
Иван ответил очень искренне,
Мол, нету рифмы к слову «истина»,

Ведь истина – она таинственна,
Она едина и единственна,
Нам недоступно знанье истины,
Как постижение Евхаристии.